# Why is my cover image being made grey in my MOBI file?

Tags: kindle

I am creating a .MOBI file for upload to Amazon's Kindle services. I have a cover image that contains a lot of white.

When I view the image in my Kindle app on my Android device, which has full colour, the cover has been made grey so that all the colours look less saturated, and the white areas are a distinct grey colour.

Why is my cover image being made grey?

I have tried using PNG and JPG formats, and that does not seem to have helped in any way.

---

I've discovered this isn't a problem specific to my book, but in how the Kindle app handles images in general. Here are some explanatory images, using the book "Guitar Zero" as an example.

In the book selector interface, the white areas of the cover are white:

[image: book cover with white]

But when I open the book, the book cover has been greyed, and the white areas are now `#eaeaea`.

[image: book cover withg grey]

What is going on?

*(I have also sent a support request directly to Amazon, and I've sent them a link to this question to use as a reference.)*

Comment: Is the original image file CMYK or RGB? If it's CMYK, try converting it yourself to RGB (Photoshop: Image > Mode > RGB). It may be that the Amazon software does a bad job of converting from CMYK to RGB.

Comment: @Tom, thank you for replying. The image is already in RGB format. I don't believe it's possible to save a JPG format file in anything but RGB.

Comment: Oh? I know I've seen problems in ebooks because of CMYK images. Perhaps they were pngs or something.

Comment: @Tom, PNG also does not support CMYK.

Comment: I am having this same problem with ebookdroid. What's going on?